# How do "rude or abusive" flags age away?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

Some time ago, I flagged something on meta as "rude or abusive". Checking now to see what became of it, I see my flag "aged away". I understand that close votes can age away, but I didn't know that "rude or abusive" flags could age away. Is this a way for the moderators to decline a flag without declining it?

Comment: Does it say that it aged away in your flagging history? Or how did you find out that it aged away? (I did not know that such thing is possible.)

Comment: Ok, so now I found this on meta.SE: [When are moderator flags automatically dismissed as “aged away” by the system?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204327) It could give you at least partial answers.

Comment: Yes, @Martin, it said that in my flagging history. I'll check the link you've given.

Comment: @Martin, the link does confirm that the sort of flag I'm asking about can age away, so many thanks for that. It doesn't say anything about why moderators might choose to allow such a flag to age away, or whether it just happens when a flag falls through the cracks for some reason.

Comment: One of [tag:discussion] and [tag:support], please. Here, [tag:support] fits better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As explained by Martin such flags [age away after 2 and 4 days for posts and comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204327/when-are-moderator-flags-automatically-dismissed-as-aged-away-by-the-system), respectively.

"Rude or abusive" and "spam" are not flags that are intended to always (or even usually) involve a  moderator. Instead, once enough flags are accumulated the content gets deleted automatically. I think the idea is roughly that the main use-case of those flags is blatantly inappropriate stuff, so that if there is no quick accumulation of flags, then it likely does not fall in that category (while it could still be inappropriate content). However, especially for (late) comments there can be the issue of just not getting enough visibility.

Yet, moderators also get shown those flags and can and do react on them.

On your question:

> Is this a way for the moderators to decline a flag without declining it?

When enough flags accumulate the action will happen, no moderator is needed. In that sense, if a moderator is convinced such a flag should be declined, then they better actually decline it rather than to try to sit it out.

I doubt moderators *intentionally* let such a  flag unhandled to let it age away. What I think could happen is something 'in the middle,' that is, a first mod sees the flag and is not quite sure about it. Thus, they let it around for the next  one to have a second opinion, etc.

If you are still convinced the content should be deleted, I would flag it anew. For this you might use an "other" flag and explain the situation. Note that moderators can give a reason for their action on a flag when the flag is on a post (yet not a comment); thus in complicated situations you might decide to  flag the post even if it is about a comment to allow for this. (Of course this is meant for the "other" flag not "rude or abusive.")

Comment: As it happens, the post I flagged was deleted by a moderator, some days after my flag "aged away", so no further action on my part is needed or, indeed, possible – I just wanted to know how this kind of flag could age away, and I'm happy with your exposition.